# Kubernetes Cluster - WordPress Error establishing a database connection

Tags: mysql, wordpress, kubernetes

I am new to Kubernetes and trying to deploying WordPress and MySQL using the Kubernetes pod containers but its throwing the error "Error establishing a database connection" while running the Kubernetes

Below are my pod and service definition files

secret.yaml

```
    apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: sql-pass
stringData:
  password: qwe123
```

persistent-volume.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv-volume
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  capacity:
    storage: 3Gi
  hostPath:
    path: /data/pv

---

apiVersion: v1 
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: mysql-pv-claims
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  volumeMode: Filesystem 
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi

---

apiVersion: v1 
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: wp-pv-claim
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  volumeMode: Filesystem 
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
```

mysql-deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: wordpress-mysql
  labels:
    app: wordpress
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 3306
  selector:
    app: wordpress
    tier: mysql
  clusterIP: None
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: mysql-pv-claim
  labels:
    app: wordpress
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 20Gi
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: wordpress-mysql
  labels:
    app: wordpress
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: wordpress
      tier: mysql
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: wordpress
        tier: mysql
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: mysql:5.6
        name: mysql
        env:
        - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: sql-pass
              key: password
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3306
          name: mysql
        volumeMounts:
        - name: mysql-persistent-storage
          mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
      volumes:
      - name: mysql-persistent-storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: mysql-pv-claim
```

wordpress-deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: wordpress
  labels:
    app: wordpress
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      nodePort: 30001
  selector:
    app: wordpress
    tier: frontend
  type: NodePort
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: wordpress
  labels:
    app: wordpress
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: wordpress
      tier: frontend
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: wordpress
        tier: frontend
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: wordpress
        name: wordpress
        env:
        - name: WORDPRESS_DB_HOST
          value: wordpress-mysql
        - name: WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: sql-pass
              key: password
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: wordpress
        volumeMounts:
        - name: wordpress-persistent-storage
          mountPath: /var/www/html
      volumes:
      - name: wordpress-persistent-storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: wp-pv-claim
```

i dont know why after i check throwing error "Error establishing a database connection"